# Xed cursor position during git commit

Tags: git, git-commit

I've been using `xed` to write my commit messages.
`xed` remembers the last cursor position of each file.
Since the file `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` is reused for each commit message, `xed` opens with the cursor at the position I was at when I committed the previous commit.
It is a PITA to have to manually reposition the cursor back to the first line.

[X]: Where I would expect the cursor to be.

[Y]: Where the cursor is.

```
[X]

# Please enter the commit [Y] message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch develop
# Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to tell `xed` to open at a certain line.
In `.gitconfig`, simply replace

```
[core]
  editor = xed
```

by

```
[core]
  editor = xed +1
```

`xed +lineNumber` tells `xed` to open the file at the line `lineNumber`.

`+1` tells it to open the file at the first line.